# how to get ec2 instances public dns name by ansible playbook

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am playing with ansible to automate ec2 instances. I created ec2 instance and then m trying to get its public dns name via ec2_remote_facts module. but it is giving variable not defined in output.

```
playbook:

- hosts:  localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: ec2 instance facts
      ec2_remote_facts:
        region: ap-southeast-2
        filters:
          instance-state-name:  running
      register: ec2

    - debug:  var=ec2.instances.public_name


Output:PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [create ec2 instance] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ec2.instances.public_name": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0  



Output for ec2.instances.

ok: [localhost] => {
    "ec2.instances": [
        {
            "ami_launch_index": "0", 
            "architecture": "x86_64", 
            "client_token": "", 
            "ebs_optimized": false, 
            "groups": [
                {
                    "id": "sg-6c016a08", 
                    "name": "default"
                }
            ], 
            "hypervisor": "xen", 
            "id": "i-915b1813", 
            "image_id": "ami-fedafc9d", 
            "instance_profile": null, 
            "interfaces": [
                {
                    "id": "eni-96de4acf", 
                    "mac_address": "0a:14:ac:64:c4:13"
                }
            ], 
            "kernel": null, 
            "key_name": "ansible.key", 
            "launch_time": "2016-08-29T07:32:10.000Z", 
            "monitoring_state": "disabled", 
            "persistent": false, 
            "placement": {
                "tenancy": "default", 
                "zone": "ap-southeast-2c"
            }, 
            "private_dns_name": "ip-xx-xx-xx-107.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal", 
            "private_ip_address": "xx.xx.xx.107", 
            "public_dns_name": "ec2-xx-xxx-xx-80.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com", 
            "ramdisk": null, 
            "region": "ap-southeast-2", 
            "requester_id": null, 
            "root_device_type": "ebs", 
            "source_destination_check": "true", 
            "spot_instance_request_id": null, 
            "state": "running", 
            "tags": {
                "Name": "Demo"
            }, 
            "virtualization_type": "hvm", 
            "vpc_id": "vpc-abcaf4ce"
        }
    ]
}
```

what i m missing here?

Thanks

Benjo

Comment: Friendly advice: if you have `dict1.var1.var2` variable undefined, inspect what's inside `dict1.var1` to see why `var2` is not available.

Comment: updated post with ec2.instances output

Answer (score 3):

If you look closely to `ec2.instances` you may note that:

- it is a list, so you either access items by index `ec2.instances[0]` or iterate over them with `with_items:` structure.
- there is no `public_name` attribute, only `public_dns_name`.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, updated as u suggested and it is working.